# Regular expression for 6 characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need couple of regular expression in ASP.NET.

1. First should accept only 6 characters and second and third character should accept only `_` (underscore).

   Like: `a__cde`
2. And I want one other regex that should also take 6 characters and at second position it should accept only underscore (`_`) and at third position it should accept maybe underscore (`_`) or hash (`#`) and at fourth position it should accept only hash (`#`).

Note: In both the regex user can only enter: Number, Alphabets or Star (*) at any position instead of above mentioned positions.

Can any one help me out on this? I have tried by below website:

http://www.regexr.com/

But not able to generate proper regex.

Comment: what did you tried ??

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
1. ^[a-zA-Z0-9\*]__[a-zA-Z0-9\*]{3}$
2. ^[a-zA-Z0-9\*]_[_#]#[a-zA-Z0-9\*]{2}$
```