# Regular expression with 6 characters in ASP.NET

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression in ASP.NET that accept `6 characters` and

1. At second position it should accept only `underscore (_)` and
2. At third position it should accept maybe `underscore (_)` or `hash (#)`
   and
3. At fourth position it should accept only `hash (#)`.

**Note**: In regex user can only enter: `Number`, `Alphabets` or `Star (*)` at any position instead of above mentioned positions.

Can any one help me out on this?

**Like**:

1. a__cde
2. ab##cd
3. a_#cde
4. ******
5. abcdef
6. 123456

Comment: This question is eerily similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344296/regular-expression-for-6-characters).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following expression:

```
(?i)^(?=^(?:[a-z0-9*]*(?:#{1,2}|_{1,2})[a-z0-9*]*|[a-z0-9*]*)$).{6}$
```

Will match:

- `a__cde`
- `ab##cd`
- `******`
- `abcdef`
- `123456`

Won't match:

- `a_#cde`
- `a_##aa`
- `A__#BC`
- `_##*`

Comment: you can replace `(?:_|#)` with `[_#]`

Comment: Number,Alphbates,*(at any position),_(at 2 & 3 Position),#(at 3 & 4 Postion). note:- _ will not come single.it will come always in pair like (a__bcd). same with #.

Comment: @Neeraj, You will have to explain the requirements in a bit more detail. Would you mind updating your question with a list of expected matches and expected non matches?

Comment: Matches:- (a__cde),(ab##cd),(******),(abcdef),(123456).                                        Won't match: (a_#cde),(a_##aa),(A__#BC),(*_##**) above four expression contain _ and # single.

Comment: @Neeraj I've updated the answer to match your expected outputs. Feel free to test it with more values.